# How to add SOAP interface for Delphi Synapse HTTP Server?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-7

I've got a custom HTTP Server created using Delphi 7 and Ararat Synapse which receives HTTP GET from another application with a simple set of variables.

For example:  http://myserver.com/get?Variable1=adsds&Variable2=asdasdasdsa&Variable3=aasdsadasdsad

The application source is similar to this - http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/13374072

Now, my customer needs me provide a SOAP interface.  Completely new to SOAP, I did some research and found it to be very complicated.  I would like to know what's the easier way to incorporate this interface to my HTTP server.  Or should I find ready made SOAP To HTTP Conversion app if there is such a software.  Thank you.

Note: I'm not the original developer of the HTTP Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Web Service Toolkit](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit) for Free Pascal and Delphi which can be used to write SOAP servers.

I have not yet used it myself but it is in active development and might be compatible with Synapse.

Update: the current version seems to include support for Internet Direct (Indy) and Synapse (HTTP server and TCP server).

Comment: +1 This is a great library, cross-platform and maintained. It uses Synapse for its HTTP server.

Comment: @mjn - Thanks mjn, do you know where I can download the latest version?  I could only find v0.5 on sourceforge.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joshua the up to date sources are available (Subversion) at https://lazarus-ccr.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/lazarus-ccr/wst/trunk

Comment: @mjn Thanks.  I managed to download the files using wget, e.g.  wget -e robots=off --wait 1 -r -I /svnroot/lazarus-ccr/wst/trunk/ https://lazarus-ccr.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/lazarus-ccr/wst/trunk/

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a SOAP server, which not only generates SOAP responses from SOAP requests, but which also provides a WSDL document telling the users what requests they can make.

Since your completely new to SOAP here are some 'starter' links:

General:

[SOAP, WDSL, HTTP, XSD? What the?](http://www.rpg-xml.com/Articles/AcronymnArticle.html)
[List of publicly available web services](http://www.xmethods.com/ve2/index.po) (I would start writring a small testapp that consumes SOAP)

With Delphi:

[Developing Web Services with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/webservices/Developing_Web_Services_with_Delphi.htm)
[Web Services Made Easy With Delphi](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Web-Services-Made-Easy-With-Delphi/)
[Web services with Delphi](http://www.onlinedelphitraining.com/newsletters/webservices.htm)

The fact that you are using Delphi 7 makes things more difficult, since later versions have better support:
[Debugging/Testing Win32 SOAP Web Services (D2007)](http://www.bobswart.nl/Weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:1424). Bob has [more SOAP articles](http://www.drbob42.com/soap/index.htm)

For testing both serving and consuming SOAP you should use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), a great free tool ([What is SOAPUI?](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html)).

Once you are up to the WDSL you [should know what types of WSDL exist](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-namespace/index.html) and the whole namespaces mess...